# How can I find out if a MUC exists using Smack?

Tags: xmpp, smack, multiuserchat

Working with [Smack 4.3.0](https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack) in a Multi User Chat ([XEP-0045-1.21](https://xmpp.org/extensions/attic/xep-0045-1.21.htm)) I'm trying to find out if a room is already created or not, but I'm not sure if what I'm doing is the correct way.
I have search for it and the most relative answer to it was [does MUC exist?](https://discourse.igniterealtime.org/t/does-muc-exist/69791).

Technically speaking:

1. Rooms are created as public and members-only by default in OpenFire 4.2.0.
2. All room's names are an id defined by the members name in a hash string i.e. `XXXXXX029d8c36b62259d0eXXXXXXXX`. This means that user A can create a room with B, C and get a `groupId` like the previous one, but then user B (in another device) can try to create same room (with users A,B,C), which is going to give him same `groupId`.
3. Exist a architecture layer like whatsapp, so users can leave a `Group Chat` and rejoin whenever they want.

What I'm doing at this moment:

```
@WorkerThread
public boolean isGroupChatAlreadyCreated(@NonNull final String groupId)
        throws
        XmppStringprepException,
        XMPPException.XMPPErrorException,
        MultiUserChatException.NotAMucServiceException,
        SmackException.NotConnectedException,
        InterruptedException,
        SmackException.NoResponseException {
    List<HostedRoom> hostedRooms = manager.getHostedRooms(JidCreate.domainBareFrom(serviceDomain));
    for (HostedRoom hostedRoom : hostedRooms) {
        if (hostedRoom.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(groupId)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

where `manager` is `MultiUserChatManager manager` and `serviceDomain` is just a `String`.

so, **the questions**: is this right way to do it? can it be improved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the easier way is get some info about room, for example its configuration form. If nothing will be returned then it means room does not exist:

```
public boolean isGroupChatAlreadyCreated(@NonNull final EntityBareJid groupId)
        throws
        XMPPErrorException,
        NotConnectedException,
        InterruptedException,
        NoResponseException {

    MultiUserChat multiUserChat = MultiUserChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection).getMultiUserChat(groupId);

    return multiUserChat.getConfigurationForm() != null;
}
```

More info here https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack/blob/4.3/smack-extensions/src/main/java/org/jivesoftware/smackx/muc/MultiUserChat.java#L809

Answer (score 1):

It is essentially the right way.

Ideally you simply use [`MulitUserChatManager.getRoomInfo(EntityBareJid)`](https://download.igniterealtime.org/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/muc/MultiUserChatManager.html#getRoomInfo-org.jxmpp.jid.EntityBareJid-). The method will return a `RoomInfo` if the room exists, or throw if it does not.

Your original approach can also be improved by changing the type of 'groupId' to `EntityBareJid` using `equals()` instead of `equalsIgnoreCase()`. And putting your groupId as Localpart of the MUC's address. So your function becomes:

```
public boolean isGroupChatAlreadyCreated(@NonNull final EntityBareJid groupId)
        throws
        XmppStringprepException,
        XMPPErrorException,
        NotAMucServiceException,
        NotConnectedException,
        InterruptedException,
        NoResponseException {
    List<HostedRoom> hostedRooms = manager.getHostedRooms(JidCreate.domainBareFrom(serviceDomain));
    for (HostedRoom hostedRoom : hostedRooms) {
        if (hostedRoom.getJid().equals(groupId)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: I believe it's not an optimal one because what will happen if your server has 100K rooms? You will have a 100K iterations loop each time at client side which can potentially lead to ANR which is not good. I have an alternative suggestion (provided in a separate answer)

Comment: Good point. I hadn't considered large result sets. I would probably use XEP-0045 § 6.4. Will update my answer later.

Comment: In my case we will not have so many rooms and plus I marked that method with `@WorkerThread`. In the worst case I can implement a binary search, but I'm pretty sure we won't need it (in our case).

Anyway I will implement the best one :D

Comment: Right. If you get an ANR then you are doing it wrong anyways. Still, if XEP-0045 provides a O(1) mechanism to lookup a room, then we should aim for it, instead of the O(n) approach.